# How to select a road on Google Map?

Tags: google-maps

I have a problem. When clicking a position on Google Map, I want to get the road segment that position belongs to and draw that segment, just like the method "Edit -> Select Road Segments" at http://www.google.com/mapmaker?hl=en
But I did not find any API can help me do that #_#.

Do u have any reference for me?
thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue, I need to be able to "select roads", and then parse that data somehow, I will try and remember to report back here if I find a solution for us :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the mousemove events to record the coordinates and store them in an array and then display the road segment by tracking the click events.

Try this: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html